# Retrieving user Id and language parameters to embedded web-component from the target site

Tags: reactjs, parameters, web-component

I am absolutely new to making web-components and have little experience with React.
I have a web-component (Direflow) embedded into the "big" site. The component is pretty simple, but has several parameters such as userId and locale. I tried with hardcoded parameters for testing but now I want it to get them from that site because each user needs access only to their own items on the service.
The HTML tag for embedding looks like this:

```
<service
 locale="en"
 userId="defaultId"
/>
```

And what I don't understand is whether I can simply change the hardcoded values for the user Id and locale values actually used in the target site e.g. `locale="props.locale"` or should use some more sophisticated way to get data about the user. If it's not that simple, could you guide me where to find more information about it. Santa Google didn't really help me.

Comment: To be strict. The  ``web-component`` tag is for W3C Standard Web Components. A newer **standard** technology developed by Browser vendors Apple, Google, Microsoft and Mozilla (Firefox) Alas not supported by Facebooks React yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it is, in my case:

```
locale={userLocale}
```

etc.